# How Can I Count Object's in Array With Given Property Value (Angular-FirebaseRealtime)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database

https://prnt.sc/qo0iig

I want to count 'statu' when it's true. How can I ?

component.ts

```
getAttDetails(ıd){
        this.afAuth.user.subscribe(user => this.serviceCourses.getAttDetails(ıd,user).subscribe(detail => console.log(detail)));
      }
```

serviceCourses

```
getAttDetails(ıd,user:firebase.User){
    return  this.db.list('/denemeDersler/'+ıd+'/attendance/'+user.uid).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => changes
      .map(c => ({key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()}))));
   }
```

Comment: Do you want to count number of keys in object?

Comment: no ı want to my objects have 'statu' and ı want to count statu when it's true

Comment: Please don't use links to add detail to your post. The link will eventually expire, making your post less valuable to user having a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

let assume your data set is like this

```js
let arr = [{key : '2020-01-15', statu : true},{key : '2020-01-11', statu : true},{key : '2020-01-10', statu : false}]

let count = 0;
arr.map(item=> { if(item.statu === true){ count++ } })
console.log(count) // output : 2
```

Comment: <https://prnt.sc/qo1cc2>       'statu' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: first console.log that what's is coming inside `listTrue` ?

Comment: @zafer in which `variable` you are getting `array` of `objects` like in your first screenshot?

Comment: ıchange my array object to any the problem is gone but When I first click I see zero but I need to see 4.https://prnt.sc/qo1ito

Comment: @zafer if this solution helped you so accept the answer so others can also take assistance from this.